# Подключить файл к DB

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, база-данных, json

Ребята ,с базой данных еще никогда не сталкивался вообще по этому не судите строго . Вчера только попробовал создать базу называется "new_tech_user"  в ней есть таблица "tab_1" и соответственно создал столбцы ID , result1,result2,result3,result4  . Есть кнопка по нажатию на которую должно якобы записываться  "1" в result1 и присвоено для ID-"1" (ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ ID -"1" ) при повторном нажатии записывается "0" .
через  JSON локально получается ,а вот как это все с базой данных связать не знаю ((

**КНОПКА ПО НАЖАТИЮ КОТОРОЙ ЗАПИСЫВАЕТСЯ 1 ИЛИ 0 В result1**

```
<button  id="user-work" onclick="Working()"><span id="text-user-work">РАБОТА</span></button>
</td>
<td>
<div id="result1"class="group-result">0</div>
</td>
```

**СКРИПТ ДЛЯ ОБРАБОТКИ НАЖАТИЯ НА КНОПКУ 1 (ЗЕЛЕНОГО ЦВЕТА ЗАКРАШИВАЕТСЯ) 0 (СЕРОГО)**

```
<script>
   var result1 = 0;
function Working() {
  if (result1 == 0) {
document.getElementById('user-work').style.backgroundColor = '#3aff3a';
    result1 = 1;
document.getElementById('bisness-trip').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result2 = 0;    
document.getElementById('holiday').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result3 = 0;
document.getElementById('user-notwork').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result4 = 0;    
  } else {
document.getElementById('user-work').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result1 = 0;
document.getElementById('bisness-trip').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result2 = 0;
document.getElementById('holiday').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result3 = 0;
document.getElementById('user-notwork').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result4 = 0;   
  }
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function ()
  {
  if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
    document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = result1;
    document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = result2;
    document.getElementById('result3').innerHTML = result3;
    document.getElementById('result4').innerHTML = result4;  
    }
  }
  xhr.open('GET','/tech_user/con_data_ajax/work-ajax-data.php?result1='+result1, true); //url по которому будет выполнятся запрос
  xhr.send(); 
} 
</script>
```

**ЗАПИСЬ В ФОРМАТЕ JSON. Путь к самой папке (/tech_user/con_data_ajax/work-ajax-data.php)**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');// разрешение на возврат данных с СЕРВЕРА !!!!
if(isset($_GET['result1']))
   {
if($_GET['result1']=="0")

echo '{"ID":"1", "result1":"0"}';

else if($_GET['result1']=="1")

echo '{"ID":"1", "result1":"1"}';
   }
?>
```

**НАЧАЛ СОЗДАВАТЬ БАЗУ ДАННЫХ И ЗАГРУЗ**

```
<?php

$hostname = "localhost"; // название/путь сервера
$username = "root"; // имя пользователя 
$password = "a-1800"; // пароль пользователя 
$dbName = "new_tech_user"; // название базы данных
/* Создаем соединение */
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbName );
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error("Подключиться к серверу не удалось:(");
    exit();
} 
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tab_1");
?>
```

Comment: Я если честно не совсем понял что нужно, Вам нужно в БД записать изменения? Тогда по идеи `echo '{"ID":"1", "result1":"0"}';` - вот вы это выводите, и сразу там-же можно делать запрос в БД на обновление. Или вы не знаете как запрос составить? Вы уже делали запрос `$sql`, просто вместо `SELECT` придется погуглить `UPDATE` ;)

Comment: В том то и дело что не знаю как его грамотно и просто составить чтоб не был нагроможден всем + не знаю как сделать чтоб result1 записывалось только для первого ID  не для второго или третьего ,а именно в первую строчку то есть ID-1

Comment: Гуглил ,там все усложненно ,а ведь уверен что можно это сделать все более компактно

Comment: `$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE tab_1 SET result1='1' WHERE id='1'");` - Так?

Comment: Компактно можно сделать если использовать фреймворки, у вас тут не получится компактно :)

Comment: Это для одного result1 id а если там будет например result2,result3,result4 и для каждого свой номер id  то так и записывать $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE tab_1 SET result1='1' WHERE id='1',result2='1' WHERE id='2',result3='1' WHERE id='3',result4='1' WHERE id='4'"); или нет ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80692/discussion-between-technoimpex-technoimpex-and-manitikyl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**/tech_user/con_data_ajax/work-ajax-data.php**

В самом начале скрипта инклудим ваше подключение к БД, только без:

`$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tab_1");`

И вставляем запросы, получается как-то так:

```
<?php
include('/connect.php');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');// разрешение на возврат данных с СЕРВЕРА !!!!
if(isset($_GET['result1']))
{
    if($_GET['result1']=="0")
    {
        mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE tab_1 SET result1='0' WHERE id='1'"); 
        echo '{"ID":"1", "result1":"0"}';
    }elseif($_GET['result1']=="1") {
        mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE tab_1 SET result1='1' WHERE id='1'"); 
        echo '{"ID":"1", "result1":"1"}';
    }
}
?>
```